# How can I add labels to each dot on my scatter plot? Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter

first post on here. Started toying around with the NFLScrapr package in python and am trying to create a scatter plot to display some info. Right now the scatter plot is only showing dots but I was wondering if there were a way to add labels to each plot from the corresponding data?

Started off with this

```py
league_rushing_success = data.loc[(data['play_type']=='run') & (data['down']<=4)].groupby(by='posteam')[['epa','success','yards_gained']].mean()
```

trying to plot with this

```py
#Make x and y variables for success rate data
x = league_rushing_success['success'].values
y = league_rushing_success['epa'].values
types = league_rushing_success['posteam'].values

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))

#Make a scatter plot with success rate data
ax.scatter(x, y,)

#Adding labels and text
ax.set_xlabel('Rush Success Rate', fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylabel('EPA', fontsize=14)
ax.set_title('Rush Success Rate and EPA', fontsize=18)
ax.text(.46, .39, 'Running Backs Dont Matter', fontsize=10, alpha=.7)

for i,type in enumerate(types):
    x = x_coords[i]
    y = y_coords[i]
    plt.scatter(x, y, marker='x', color='red')
    plt.text(x+0.3, y+0.3, type, fontsize=9)
```

The error I'm getting is

```py
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2656             try:
-> 2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'posteam'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-81-ebdc88aed0ac> in <module>
      2 x = league_rushing_success['success'].values
      3 y = league_rushing_success['epa'].values
----> 4 types = league_rushing_success['posteam'].values
      5 
      6 fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2925             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2926                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2927             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2928             if is_integer(indexer):
   2929                 indexer = [indexer]

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:
-> 2659                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2660         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2661         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'posteam'
```

[image]

Comment: To summarize, you try something like `df["colname"]`, but `"colname"` is not the name of a column in `df`. The reason is that you have previously grouped by that column, so it's not part of the data anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line gives you an error because `posteam` is an index:

```py
# error
types = league_rushing_success['posteam'].values

# try this
types = league_rushing_success.reset_index()['posteam'].values
```

---

From your code it is also not very clear what `x_coords` and `y_coords` mean (and would give you an error, too):

```py
for i,type in enumerate(types):
    x = x_coords[i] # would give name 'x_coords' is not defined
    y = y_coords[i] # 'y_coords' is not defined
```

If you want to add labels to a plot, it might be a good idea to look into  [`matplotlib.pyplot.annotate`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.annotate)

```py
# I would use something like this instead of `plt.text`
for i, txt in enumerate(types):
    ax.annotate(txt, (x[i], y[i]), xytext=(10,10), textcoords='offset points')
    plt.scatter(x, y, marker='x', color='red')
```

---

To sum it up:

```py
x = league_rushing_success['success'].values
y = league_rushing_success['epa'].values
types = league_rushing_success.reset_index()['posteam'].values

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
ax.scatter(x, y)

ax.set_xlabel('Rush Success Rate', fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylabel('EPA', fontsize=14)
ax.set_title('Rush Success Rate and EPA', fontsize=18)

for i, txt in enumerate(types):
    ax.annotate(txt, (x[i], y[i]), xytext=(10,10), textcoords='offset points')
    plt.scatter(x, y, marker='x', color='red')
```

[image]

Points are randomly generated, but the style of the plot should be the same.

I hope this helps.